# Regex: Match everything in text paragraph except specific phrases

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm writing a free plugin for Google Docs and processing paragraphs of text.

I need a regular expression to match everything except a **phrase** (i.e. multiple words separated with spaces).

For example, when searching the text `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` I want to match everything except `quick brown` and `lazy` with the expected result being `The fox jumped over the dog`.

`\b((?!(lazy)\b).)+`
This works; it matches all text except `lazy` and I get `The quick brown fox jumped over the dog`.

`\b((?!(quick brown|lazy)\b).)+`
This does not work; it leaves in `brown` and I get `The brown fox jumped over the dog` when I should get `The fox jumped over the dog`

I've searched the web for hours on this and haven't had any luck.  The regex is missing something and I don't know what it is.

Thanks for reading!

RegEx Example: **https://regex101.com/r/3HGiff/1**
Javascript Example: **https://jsfiddle.net/g85je2aj/16/**

**EDIT/update:** I developed another solution, but it relies on a positive lookbehind, which is only supported by Chrome.

`((?<=(quick brown|lazy)+(?=[\s]))|^(?!(quick brown|lazy))).+?((?=(quick brown|lazy))|$)`

RegEx Example: **https://regex101.com/r/3HGiff/3**
Javascript Example: **https://jsfiddle.net/g85je2aj/19/**

Since that only works in Chrome, I don't think it's a real solution.  Any thoughts on how to modify that regex to not use a lookbehind, or is that impossible?

Comment: The regex you have matches each word boundary first, then matches any char, 1+ occurrences, that is not a starting point for some sequence. It matches up to `w` in `word`, or `t` in `two`, thus the next word boundary after `one` or `two` is matched and goes on matching up to the next `one` or `two`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Wiktor.  Unfortunately, I don't think I'm any closer to an answer.

Comment: You are very close. You do not need to match any text but some other text. Just share a sample test case, a snippet in JS (use jsfiddle.net or add code to the question) and explain what you need to get as a result.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I updated the post with better examples, both on regex101 and jsfiddle.

Comment: If I were you, I'd match the given phrases and use `replaceAll` to remove them

Comment: Hi GalAbra - thanks for the idea!  Unfortunately, using a `replaceAll` function won't work as I need each part of the text between the excluded words delivered as a separate string.  For example, I need `The ` and `fox jumped over the ` and `dog.` ... I can't use the whole filtered sentence `The fox jumped over the dog.`

Comment: @user9270866 Just use a splitting approach - see https://jsfiddle.net/g85je2aj/22/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew THANK YOU!!!  Using a splitting approach did the trick.  No more messy regex!  If you put that as an answer I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching all text that does not match some string(s), you may use a *splitting* approach. You may use a list of phrases you need to avoid getting to build an alternation based regex and use it with `String#split()`:

```
var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + phrasesToSearchFor + ")\\b","i");
var results =  textToSearchIn.split(regExp);
```

All you need to do later is access all the items in the `results` array.

Here is the JS demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function () {
  //the text to search for words in, then inverse highlight
  var textToSearchIn = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
  //phrases to search for in a regex-friendly format
  //please note: this string vary in length and number of phrases 
  //  as it is parsed from an array of phrases using array.join('|');  
  var phrasesToSearchFor = "quick brown|lazy";
  //build a new regular expression to match everything but the phrasesToSearchFor
  //the best regex I have figured out is:  \b((?!(quick brown|lazy)\b).)+
  //but it only works for single-word phrases
  var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + phrasesToSearchFor + ")\\b","i");
  //do a while loop to collect all the matches
  var results =  textToSearchIn.split(regExp);
  for (var result of results) {
    //format the matche as a list item.  we only need the first group [0]
    var result = $('<li>' + result + '</li>');
    //send the match to the html list
    $('#output').before(result);
  }
  /* expected output:  
     * The 
     * fox jumped over the 
     * dog.
    actual output:    
     * The 
     * brown fox jumped over the 
     * dog.
  */
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click to test</button>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use capturing groups instead:

```
(.*)(one|two words)\s(.*)
```

Then you could get your text without the specified words by using: `$1$3`.

**Example:** [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1FbkPI/4)

Comment: Hi Pedro - thanks for the idea!  Unfortunately it doesn't work if the match is in there multiple times - e.g. `sentence has foo and then foo again` it will only catch one of the `foo`'s