# Java Regex: Remove all except specific phrases and words

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to remove everything except certain phrases. I was wondering if there was a neat solution to this using only regular expressions:

```
String strEthnicity = "the person should be East Asian or African American or Hispanic.";
String strRegex = "\\b(?!hispanic|caucasian|african american|east asian))\\b\\S+";

strEthnicity = strEthnicity.toLowerCase().replaceAll(strRegex,"");
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't work well with phrases, just single words...

> It returns: "east african hispanic"
>
> Instead of: "east asian african american hispanic"

I tried using parentheses and I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456625/regex-match-everything-in-text-paragraph-except-specific-phrases) which seems similar, but I wanted to see if there's a better solution than the one given (it's also not java so hopefully not considered a duplicate)

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this. Do a Rabin-Karp algorithm. You can also tokenize your text, remove the words that have a match in a `Set` of words you want to remove and then rebuild the text.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesnt work well with phrases"? Can you make a clear concrete example of input, expected output and current output?

Comment: @Zabuza I edited it hopefully it makes more sense. I will look up Rabin Karp algorithm because I have no idea what that is :) thank you

Comment: It is an efficient solution to walk through a text from left to right and see if your "window" matches a given word. Not sure if its applicable for you because I didnt fully get your question. If your window size isnt known in advance then its probably not as good. But the other approach should work fine.

Comment: So you want to remove everything from a text except a list of some substrings?

Comment: @Zabuza yes exactly. Right now I’m using your token advice and it seems like a nice workaround. 
I don’t know the size of the input I will be receiving :/

Comment: The token approach also suffers from the fact that your substrings can consist of multiple words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(?i)\\b(hispanic|caucasian|african american|east asian)\\b` as the regex.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strEthnicity = "the person should be East Asian or African American or Hispanic.";
        String strRegex = "(?i)\\b(hispanic|caucasian|african american|east asian)\\b";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strRegex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strEthnicity);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
East Asian
African American
Hispanic
```

Note that `(?i)` is there to ignore case so that you do not need to convert the string to any case.